# Click Once and ActiveX

Tags: .net, clickonce, c#-2.0

I have my "clickonce" windows form app working except for the installation of a com "ActiveX" element. The users machines have almost no permissions ie they cannot install or even navigate to a website outside one. I am a little stumped as to how include the activex control without registering or installing it. Has anyone else ran into this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a registration-free load of your COM DLL using a manifest file. See  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188708.aspx#S1 for more info.

**Edit:**

The link seems to be dead. Here is a registration-free activation of **COM components** MSDN [walk-through](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx).
There is also registration-free activation of **.NET-based components** MSDN [walk-through](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973915.aspx).

Comment: Don't miss the fact that registration-free COM only works in Windows XP and later. While .Net 2.0 with ClickOnce still works on Windows 98 and 2000.

Comment: [MSDN: Deploying COM Components with ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165432.aspx) is an up-to-date   article.